# How to parse json into nested html list strucuture

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried this with xml, but the behavior was odd from firefox to IE.
I haven't worked with json before, so any help would be appreciated.

here's my json:

```
{
   "storeList":{
      "state":[
         {
            "stateName":"Maine",
            "store":[
               {
                  "storeName":"Store 1",
                  "storeID":"store1",
                  "storeURL":"http:\/\/www.sitename.com"
               },
               {
                  "storeName":"Store 2",
                  "storeID":"store2",
                  "storeURL":"http:\/\/www.sitename.com"
               },
               {
                  "storeName":"Store 3",
                  "storeID":"store3",
                  "storeURL":"http:\/\/www.sitename.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "stateName":"Connecticut",
            "store":[
               {
                  "storeName":"Store 1",
                  "storeID":"store1",
                  "storeURL":"http:\/\/www.sitename.com"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and the structure I'm going for -

```
<div id="storeList">
    <ul>
       <li>
          <h3>State Name 1</h3>
          <a href="storeurl" id="storeid">storename</a>
          <a href="storeurl" id="storeid">storename</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <h3>State Name 2</h3>
          <a href="storeurl" id="storeid">storename</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***update***

tried a solution below, loading the json from an external file, but I get an error that object is not defined:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    var object;
                    $.getJSON('xml/storeList.json', function(json) {
                      object = json;
                    });


                    $('#storeList').append('<ul/>')
                    $.each(object.storeList.state, function() {
                        var list = $('#storeList ul'),
                        listItem = $('<li/>'),
                        html = listItem.append($('<h3/>').text(this.stateName));

                        $.each(this.store, function() {
                        listItem.append($('<a />').attr('href', this.storeURL).text(this.storeName));
                        });

                        list.append(html)
                    });
                    });
```

Comment: There's nothing to JSON. If you know how to deal with a Javascript data structure, you can use JSON. Given `var x = blah blah blah;` in some javascript, JSON is the `blah blah blah` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
$('#storeList').append('<ul/>')
$.each(object.storeList.state, function() {
    var list = $('#storeList ul'),
        listItem = $('<li/>'),
        html = listItem.append($('<h3/>').text(this.stateName));

    $.each(this.store, function() {
        listItem.append($('<a />').attr('href', this.storeURL).text(this.storeName));
    });

    list.append(html)

});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K3rrx/1)

***EDIT***

```
var object;
$.getJSON('xml/storeList.json', function(json) {
    object = json;
    $('#storeList').append('<ul/>')
    $.each(object.storeList.state, function() {
        var list = $('#storeList ul'),
            listItem = $('<li/>'),
            html = listItem.append($('<h3/>').text(this.stateName));

        $.each(this.store, function() {
            listItem.append($('<a />').attr('href', this.storeURL).text(this.storeName));
        });

        list.append(html)
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not having any success getting a json file from outside with this.

Comment: @Jason, I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: my json isn't inline, but in separate file. I'm trying to use getJSON, but it's not working correctly for me.

Comment: @Jason Then please post a new question explaining that, because that is your real issue.

Comment: I'm just wondering how to load the json from an outside file with your solution, instead of inline json.

Comment: @Jason, you were using object before it was ready. My update fixes that

Comment: Works - my div was being loaded dynamically from an xml file, so I had to put the script into the xml, to run after the div was created. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a template engine. With a template engine you can define your template (which is easy to read and maintain) like that:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <ul>
        {{#each state}}
        <li>
            <h3>{{=stateName}}</h3>
            {{#each store}}
            <a href="{{=storeURL}}" id="{{=storeID}}">{{=storeName}}</a>
            {{/each}}
       </li>
       {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

and then simply call

```
$("#storeList").html(
    $("#template").render(json.storeList)
);
```

to fill your div

```
<div id="storeList"></div>
```

I have a [demo ready](http://jsfiddle.net/u3JyH/8/). The template engine I use here is [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender).

Comment: A classic example of swatting a fly with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Do you think that appending DOM elements in loops or string concatenation is a better approach then? Is a 18K javascript library a "sledgehammer"???

Comment: Using a library at all is a sledgehammer, if a simple `for` loop will do the job just as clearly and much more quickly. If you don't like appending DOM elements in loops, then push them onto an array and append them all at once like you ought to.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Using templates is easier to maintain, respects separation of concerns (I really hate creating DOM elements in my javascript code) and personally I find it to be more elegant. JsRender is a personal choice (optimized for high performance) but there are templates engines that are just 20 lines of code (John Resig's micro-templating).

Answer (score 2):

JSON is nothing but a subset of Javascript object literal notation that allows nested objects and/or arrays, so you will want to study up on the Javascript object and array data structures.

That being said, once your "bare" json is assigned to a variable, let's assume "json" (test by prepending with "json=") you can probably begin to work with your JSON in the following manner, just as you would with an array:

```
for (var i=0, n=json.storeList.state.length; i<n; i++) {
    var state = json.storeList.state[i];
    console.log(state.stateName); //Maine, then Connecticut
    for (var j=0, k=state.store.length; j<k; j++) {
        var store = state.store[j]; //the object containing store name, id & URL
        console.log(store.storeID);
    }
}
```

PS....my answer is "pure" Javascript as opposed to using jQuery, so if you're committed to doing things the jQuery way, definitely consider the other answers.  But it's good to get familiar with the Javascript foundation behind the various frameworks such as jQuery, ExtJS, etcetera, in case you ever have to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `$.each()` function to iterate over object properties, and just a standard for loop for iterating over the arrays.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ6U4/

And the code:

```
var htmlStr = '';

$.each(myObj, function(i,v){
    htmlStr += '<div id="' + i + '">';
    $.each(v, function(i, v){
        htmlStr += '<ul>';
        for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
            htmlStr += '<li><h3>' + v[i].stateName + '</h3>';
            for(var n = 0; n < v[i].store.length; n++){
                var store = v[i].store[n];
                htmlStr += '<a href="' + store.storeURL + '" id="' + store.storeID + '">' + store.storeName + '</a>';
            }
            htmlStr += '</li>';
        }
        htmlStr += '</ul>';
    });
    htmlStr += '</div>';
});
```